# Did not check() all arguments during subsequent method call

Tags: meteor

When I make a Meteor method call, if it's only invoked once, everthing is fine. However, if i make the same call multiple times during the same connection, Meteor will throw 'Did not check() all argument ...' error.

Say I have a method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  testCheck: function(arg) {
    check(arg, Match.Any);
    return arg;
  }
});
```

Now, if I call it like this:

```
Meteor.call('testCheck', 1, function(err, data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

... everthing is fine. However, if I call like this:

```
Meteor.call('testCheck', 1, function(err, data) {
  console.log(data);
  Meteor.call('testCheck', 2, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Meteor will throw error on the second call. Am I doing something wrong? Is anybody else having the same problem? I'm using Meteor Windows 0.2.0.

Comment: Could not reproduce on pad: http://meteorpad.com/pad/oT2kHrRG3XM2KxrGD/ (Warning: I used two alerts in the code)

Comment: This is weird. I'll try a new Meteor installation and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem on my Meteor install. Turns out I had [easy-security](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-security) package installed, and it's setting a rate limit on Meteor calls.
Uninstalling this worked for me, however this is not really a good solution (I did not have time yet to look further).
If this is also the cause of your issue, you should consider tweaking it into allowing your calls rather than uninstalling it.

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, removing easy-security indeed solved the problem. As I'm in the early stage of my project, doing without the package is fine for now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Strange but also solved my problem :( @blackcat have you found any other work around instead removing the package

Comment: Afraid not, it was kind of a side project and I didn't have much time for it.

Comment: I went on their github page and the package is now deprecated. The reason being most of it (e.g. DDPRateLimiter) is now part of Meteor core, and the rest is done better in other packages. It's pretty safe to just uninstall it.